# c++ array initialization special manner

Tags: c++

The following code is working smoothly in C while doen't work in C++. Why?
During compilation it shows the following error

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:5:36: sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
  int arr[50] = {0,1,2,[47]=47,48,49};
```

CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
     int arr[50] = {0,1,2,[47]=47,48,49};
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't fathom any self-respecting C compiler accepting this code. Whatever this is supposed to do, it's wrong.

Comment: It seems because it is not a feature in standard C++ and your compiler doesn't support it, [clang 3.8.0 can compile it](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/GcqkIKFpLyf0IW6B),

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This should be a valid C99 (or later) code if the first two C++-specific lines are removed.

Comment: Please add the following information to your post:  compiler name and version, command line parameters to the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The code given is not legal in C++11, it's a designated initializer specified in ISO C99.

GCC supports the structure field naming part of the specification (e.g. `union D { int i; double d; }; D d { .d = 1.2; }`) as an extension in C++  but not the array indexing part.

See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Designated-Inits.html:

> Standard C90 requires the elements of an initializer to appear in a fixed order, the same as the order of the elements in the array or structure being initialized.
>
> In ISO C99 you can give the elements in any order, specifying the array indices or structure field names they apply to, and GNU C allows this as an extension in C90 mode as well. This extension is not implemented in GNU C++.